# Error mounting Root File System

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux

I am trying to run a linux RFS on an IMX51 Freescale board.
I got the uboot running along with the kernel. I followed http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/i.MX51+EVK#i.MX51EVK-FirstBoot%3A for instructions. However The problem I have now is the kernel stalls while mounting the Root file system with the following error:

mount: only root can do that (effective UID is 1000)
mountall : Filesystem could not be mounted: /sys/fs/fuse/connections
mountall:mount /sys/fs/fuse/connections terminated with status

...etc

How should I copy the RFS into the SD card? what permissions should be preserved while copying? what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @user900785, The error shows that it tried to mount a FUSE file system, not the root filesystem in the tutorial link (ext4). Would you mind rechecking which script tried to mount the FUSE fs?

Comment: Hi dien. Thanks, yes, I had not copied the RFS correctly so had got problems. When I copied as root user the error did not come. Although for some reason the boot stalls after the filesystems get mounted. I don't get the login prompt.

Comment: You can get access to the rootfs prompt by adding to the kernel argument the parameter "init=/bin/sh". This will by-pass all the initialization scripts under /etc/ so that you get access to the shell. With this method, you can remove the suspected script that mounts the filesystem and causes the error.